# Building multiple configurations with a single Solution Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2008

As part of my software package I need to build both a WIN32 AND an x64 version of a DLL.  I have a project setup that builds all necessary components and has a custom build step to build an installer.  I can't figure out how to have both versions of the DLL build with one build command.  The Configuration Manager allows you to select which project configuration to build for a given solution configuration but not multiple project configurations for the same project.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. If you are using .net, compile the project for 'Any CPU'. In your post-build, copy the dll and run CorFlags.exe  /32BIT+ to force the copied dll to run 32bit while the original will run x64 on the x64 OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vcbuild